# MemoryStream mangles my XML? "hexadecimal value 0x0 is illegal in XML documents."

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, xml, stream

I am really a newbie with streams, so I don't really know what I am doing here. :)

I have a `XElement` containing XML. I want it to return it as a file to the user.

```
  XElement xml = IndicesXMLGenerator.XML();

  //Code for creating a memorystream for returning to browser as file
   MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
  XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode);
  xml.Save(writer);
  writer.Close();

  //Code for direct saving to harddisk
  FileStream filestream = new FileStream(@"D:\indices.xml", FileMode.Create);
  XmlTextWriter writer2 = new XmlTextWriter(filestream, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode);
  xml.Save(writer2);
  writer2.Close();
  filestream.Close();

  //Return memorystream as fileresult
  return base.File(new MemoryStream(stream.GetBuffer()), "text/xml", "AlleIndices.xml");
    }
```

When I open the file that I got from my browser, it is totally mangled.
like: `�< ? X M L`

When I change the encoding in the code to `UTF8` it gives me a normal looking document, but at the end I get a lot of `0x0` characters that make the document invalid.

Strange thing is that the XML file that I saved directly to the harddisk from within the code is:

- Perfectly fine in it's encoding
- Doesn't contain any strange `0x0`characters

So, what's going on here? Why can't I easily stream my XElement to the browser as file?

Comment: An aside to your question: your streams and XML Reader/Writers need to be in `using` blocks, to prevent resource leaks in the case of exceptions. Also, unless you're still using .NET 1.1, you should use `XmlWriter.Create` instead of `XmlTextWriter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `GetBuffer` will return the stream's internal buffer, which will be larger than the actual data.  (In case you write some more to the stream)

You need to replace the call to `GetBuffer` with [`ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx), which will copy the used portion of the buffer to a new array.

---

However, the best way to do this is return the original MemoryStream, but first set the `Position` property to 0, like this:

```
stream.Position = 0;
return File(stream, "text/xml", "AlleIndices.xml");
```

Comment: I can't set position or seek, because stream is closed,probably due to closing of writer.
However, calling ToArray() looks like a good solution!

Comment: You should `Flush()` the writer instead of calling `Close()`.

Answer (score 1):

1. <strike>You don't need to create a new `MemoryStream`, you can just reuse the same (you just need to `Seek` to the beginning of the stream)</strike>
2. The XML appears mangled because the browser doesn't know that it's encoded as Unicode. You need to add a *Content-Encoding* header to the response to specify the encoding

Comment: Memorystream is closed when the writer closes. So yes, a new memstream is needed.

Comment: good point, I missed that... my second still stands, though ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `MemoryStream` implements an array doubling technique so that it can resize efficiently as you add bytes. This means that the buffer is usually larger than the actual data.

There are a few solutions:

1. Use `ToArray` instead of `GetBuffer`.
2. Use the `MemoryStream` constructor that takes an offset and length.

For example:

```
new MemoryStream(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)stream.Length)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will be much happier in the long run if you write your code like this:

```
XElement xml = IndicesXMLGenerator.XML();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(ms))
{
   xml.Save(xw);
}
```

1. Use `XmlWriter.Create`, not `XmlTextWriter`, and use `XmlWriterSettings` to control encoding and formatting.
2. Use `using` blocks rather than explicitly calling `Flush` and `Close` - that way you don't have to explicitly call them.

That said, none of that's actually your problem, which as noted is the use of `GetBuffer` instead of `ToArray`.  But as I said, you'll be happier in the long run.